# Can you teleport a player to a certain block without specifying the coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make it easier to move around my world but since I'm on my iPad typing is very bad. I want to type something short in my chat and then be teleported to a block I placed earlier of which there is only one in my workarea. (Mycelium or something)

Thing is, I want to be able to move that block around my workspace without constantly changing the coordinates in the command block, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can teleport players to entities and armor stands are entities so they're good markers for this purpose. Place an armor stand and name it with a name tag (such as 'pos1'). Then you can teleport the player to the armor stand with the following command.

```
/tp @p @e[name=pos1]
```

If you want to move the armor stand without having to replace and rename it, you can teleport the armor stand to your current position.

```
/tp @e[name=pos1] @p
```

If you don't want the armor stand to be visible you can grant the armor stand an invisibility effect with particles disabled for a really long time.

```
/effect @e[name=pos1] invisibility 99999999 0 true
```

If you wish to remove the armor stands you can kill them easily with commands

```
/kill @e[name=pos1]
```

There are limits to this method. Armor stands far outside render distance won't be picked up by the selector. For the default 48 chunk render distance that's in my tests it was something like 870 blocks or so which is pretty far. If you need more than that you can resort to adding /tickingarea

Comment: You can also use [scoreboard tags](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#Tags) using the `/tag` command, which are much more versatile than just using the custom name.

Comment: Yep, that works as well. Since the player is complaining about typing however, naming a name tag gives the player something reusable and 'pickable' within the game world. Tags require commands to administer and to set a tag without accidentally tagging all entities requires selectors (example: /tag @e[type=armor_stand,c=1]) so I figured mentioning name tags would be more straight forward, but yes, tags work fine for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is. however it requires setup.
there is no command in the game that allows you to do something like this but we have function files in minecraft. if you already have a command that teleports you there you can make a function file with that teleport command in it and when you run it via /function you will teleport.

however this requires a lot of time and effort to compared to copying the command from a notepad and only shaves off a few characters from the command.

however if you do want to attempt it 3rd party documentation for minecraft behaviour is available [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Add-on)